# How to pass shell script variable to erlang:exit()?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I am trying to delete stuck processes in RMQ using command `rabbitmqctl eval 'erlang:exit(c:pid("'$pid'"),kill).'` But I am having below error.

```
Error:
{:undef, [{:c, :pid, ['0,159,0'], []}, {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 680]}, {:erl_eval, :expr_list, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 888]}, {:erl_eval, :expr, 5, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 411]}, {:erl_eval, :exprs, 2, []}]}
```

Any idea to resolve this error? What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the type and value of `"'$pid'"`. Looking at the error message it looks like a string, and in this case `erlang:exit(c:pid(list_to_pid("'$pid'")),kill)` should work

Answer (score 1):

[c:pid/3](https://erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#pid-3) takes 3 integers, not a string, if you want to use a string, use [list_to_pid/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_pid-1).

The issue here is that you're trying to call

```erlang
c:pid("0,159,0"),
```

and it should be either

```erlang
c:pid(0,159,0)
```

or

```erlang
list_to_pid("<0.159.0>")
```

Comment: I thought of c:pid("0,159,0"), and suspecting tat could be the reason. But I still have a question, how do I pass Pid so that it can be ```c:pid(0,159,0)``` or ```list_to_pid("<0.159.0>")``` .. I am trying this way ```rabbitmqctl eval 'erlang:exit(list_to_pid("'$pid'"),kill).'```.  But still not working.

Comment: @dharpatel if your $pid variable is `0.159.0` (note the dots) and you use `list_to_pid`, you're missing the enclosing `<>`: `$ erl -eval 'exit(list_to_pid("<'$PROCESS_ID'>"),kill).'`

Comment: @dharpatel and if you use commas (`0,159,0`), you can use `c:pid`: `erl -eval 'exit(c:pid('$PROCESS_ID'),kill).'`

Comment: Thanks Jose. Issue already got resolved with    ```erlang:exit(c:pid('$pid'),kill)``` . But the alternate command you suggest will also work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
erlang:exit(c:pid("'$pid'"),kill)
```

`exit/2` takes two arguments: a `pid` and any erlang term(e.g. the atom `kill`).  A `pid` is not a string nor is it an integer, rather it is it's own type, which is returned by some functions, like `self/0`.  erlang outputs a pid to the shell like this:

```
<0.64.0>
```

All output to the shell is a string, but that does not mean that a pid is a string internally, so you cannot create a pid by writing `"<0.64.0>"`, just like you can't create an integer by writing `"10"`.

If you have a pid already, say `$pid`, you don't need to convert that to another type because the first argument for `exit/2` is defined to be a pid type, so you would call exit() like this:

```
erlang:exit('$pid',kill)
```

Comment: ```rabbitmqctl eval 'erlang:exit('$pid',kill).'```.    is also not working. its giving me an error.    ```Error:
{:undef, [{:erlang, :exit, [0, 159, 0, :kill], []}, {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 680]}, {:erl_eval, :exprs, 2, []}]}```

Comment: I got the solution. Basically    ```erlang:exit('$pid',kill)```    was giving     ```undef```    
   error. So I need to defin fun by     ```erlang:exit(c:pid('$pid'),kill).```      and it resolve the issue.